# Explanation of generalization of Newton's Method for multiple dimensions

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse, hessian

I've been following the [CS 229](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS229) lecture videos for machine learning, and in [lecture 4](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS229/49) (~14:00), Ng explains [Newton's Method for optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) to maximize an objective function ($f$), but doesn't clearly explain the derivation of the higher dimension generalization:

$$
\theta := H^{-1} \nabla_{\theta}\ f(\theta)
$$

I've read that the Hessian matrix ($H$) is a multiple dimension generalization of the second order derivative, but other than that I'm not sure I understand the formulation of the Hessian or why we multiply by its inverse; perhaps I need to brush up on linear algebra.

What's an intuitive explanation of the Hessian and its inverse in this formula?

Answer (score 7):

**Overview**

Suppose we want to minimize an objective function $f$ that maps a parameter vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ to a scalar value. The idea behind [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) is to locally approximate $f$ with a quadratic function, then solve for the point that minimizes this approximation. We then jump to this new point, where we build a new approximation, and repeat the process until convergence.

**Local quadratic approximation**

Say our current location in parameter space is the vector $x_0$. We can approximate $f$ in the vicinity of $x_0$ using the second order [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables):

$$f(x) \approx f_T(x) =
f(x_0) + (x-x_0)^T \nabla f(x_0) + \frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)^T H(x_0) (x-x_0)$$

This is a quadratic function whose value at $x_0$, as well as its first and second partial derivatives, match those of $f$. $\nabla f(x_0)$ is the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of $f$ evaluated at $x_0$. This is a vector containing the partial derivatives of $f$, and is analogous to the derivative for functions of single variables. Similarly, $H(x_0)$ is the [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of $f$ evaluated at $x_0$. It's a matrix containing second partial derivatives of $f$, and is analogous to the second derivative for functions of single variables.

$$\nabla f(x_0) = \left [ \matrix{
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} (x_0) \\
    \vdots \\
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_d} (x_0) \\
} \right ]
\quad
H(x_0) = \left [ \matrix{
    \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2} (x_0) &
    \cdots &
    \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_d} (x_0) \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_d \partial x_1} (x_0) &
    \cdots &
    \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_d^2} (x_0) \\
} \right ]$$

**Minimizing the local approximation**

Given the local approximation $f_T$ at the current point $x_0$, we want to find a new point $x$ that minimizes $f_T$. This can be done in closed form by taking the gradient of $f_T$ with respect to $x$, setting it to zero, then solving for $x$.

The gradient of $f_T$ can be found by differentiating the expression above (keeping in mind that $\nabla f(x_0)$ is just a fixed vector and $H(x_0)$ is just a fixed matrix):

$$\nabla f_T(x) = \nabla f(x_0) + H(x_0) (x - x_0)$$

Setting it to zero, we have:

$$H(x_0) (x - x_0) = -\nabla f(x_0)$$

We need to isolate $x$, so multiply both sides by the inverse of the Hessian, then move $x_0$ to the righthand side:

$$x = x_0 - \Big( H(x_0) \Big)^{-1} \nabla f(x_0)$$